# Is Jasypt 1.9.2 compatible with Spring 4.3.8?

Tags: spring-mvc, jasypt

We are migrating an ant based spring 3.1 app to maven based spring 4.3.8. We are encrypting our property file entries with Jasypt 1.9.2. However, when the app is started, it throws

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] for bean with name 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
```

jasypt-1.9.2 and jasypt-spring31-1.9.2 jars are available under WEB-INF/lib folder. Below is the application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="*.html" location="/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz" />
     <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
        <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
      class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
        <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxx" /> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Maven entry is :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring31</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. According to http://jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html:

Spring-integrated transparent decryption of .properties files: Jasypt can integrate into the configuration system of the Spring Framework (2.x and 3.x) and transparently decrypt .properties files used by Spring applications. Learn more: Spring 2.x, Spring 3.0, Spring 3.1.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: The folks at jasypt have released 1.9.3 which is compatible with Spring4 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

## Not directly substitutable, but can be easily fixed

We also had the `Cannot find class [org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]` when trying to upgrade to Jasypt 1.9.3.

We were using Jasypt 1.4.1 and had to migrate due to vulnerabilities, so our only option (according to the vulnerabilities scanner) was "1.9.2 or higher."

1.9.3 is not a direct substitution for 1.4.1. The class hierarchy changes and, since we had springframework 4.x, we had to use the `jasypt-spring4`artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

So our beans (we used it directly from XML with spring) now look like this:

```
<bean id="myBasicTextEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor">
    <property name="password" value="YouWishIShowYou" />
</bean>

<bean id="myPropertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring4.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <constructor-arg ref="myBasicTextEncryptor" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/properties/localSecrets.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In which the only change we had to do to make it work was adding that `4` in `org.jasypt.spring4.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

Comment: This helped me I was directly using 1.9.3 instead of jasypt-spring4 , After adding below my issue got fixed implementation group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt-spring4', version: '1.9.3'

Comment: did you find any further update on this if we need to change the dependency

Comment: @VivekPanday No, I haven't looked back. It seems to keep up with time now and did not need to change it any more.